# Matching length of subindexes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   target_q_0  target_q_1  target_q_2  target_q_3  target_q_4
sample_nr  event                                                             
1          0         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           1         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           2         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           3         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           4         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
2          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
           1         0.092376   -1.121655    1.364788   -0.204306   -0.008050
           2         0.092057   -1.119634    1.361355   -0.202632   -0.009688
           3         0.091748   -1.117672    1.358021   -0.201005   -0.011279
3          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
```

Each sample can have different amount of events.

I want to find the *longest* sample, that is a sample with the highest number of events, and *zero pad* all the other samples to match it in length.

The desired outcome would be this:

```
                   target_q_0  target_q_1  target_q_2  target_q_3  target_q_4
sample_nr  event                                                             
1          0         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           1         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           2         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           3         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
           4         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
2          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
           1         0.092376   -1.121655    1.364788   -0.204306   -0.008050
           2         0.092057   -1.119634    1.361355   -0.202632   -0.009688
           3         0.091748   -1.117672    1.358021   -0.201005   -0.011279
           4         0          0            0          0                0
3          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
           1         0          0            0          0                0
           2         0          0            0          0                0
           3         0          0            0          0                0
           4         0          0            0          0                0
```

I have a working way to do this, but it's very slow.

```
def pad_df(df):
    max_rows = df.index.get_level_values(1).max()
    for sample, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
        new_df = (new_df.unstack(level=0).reindex(list(range(max_rows)),
                                                  fill_value=0))

        new_df = new_df.stack('sample_nr').swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()
        df.loc[experiment_data.index.get_level_values(0) == sample] = new_df
```

This function is called with my full dataframe, experiment_data, as input:

```
experiment_data = load_some_stuff()
pad_df(experiment_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a magical method could not be found, a fair strategy may be pre-allocating the wanted array and populate it using for loop. This is usually much faster than direct operations on a dataframe.

The required `MultiIndex` for the answer array can be generated using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) in your case because the length of each level is fixed.

### Data

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import io
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
sample_nr  event   target_q_0  target_q_1  target_q_2  target_q_3  target_q_4
1          0         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
1          1         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
1          2         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
1          3         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
1          4         0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
2          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
2          1         0.092376   -1.121655    1.364788   -0.204306   -0.008050
2          2         0.092057   -1.119634    1.361355   -0.202632   -0.009688
2          3         0.091748   -1.117672    1.358021   -0.201005   -0.011279
3          0         0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python", index_col=["sample_nr", "event"])
```

### Code

```
# 1. compute the sizes of each sample_nr
sr_sizes = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0)).size()
# compute max size and #sample_nr
max_size = sr_sizes.max()
n_sample_nrs = len(sr_sizes)

# 2. preallocate the output array and fill
arr = np.zeros((max_size * n_sample_nrs, 5))
idx_lv0 = df.index.get_level_values(0)  # get sample_nr
for i in range(n_sample_nrs):
    row = i*max_size
    arr[row:row + sr_sizes.iloc[i], :] =\
        df[idx_lv0 == sr_sizes.index[i]].values

# 3. convert to dataframe
df_ans = pd.DataFrame(
    data=arr,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sr_sizes.index, range(max_size)]),
    columns=df.columns
).rename_axis(df.index.names, axis=0)
```

### Result

```
print(df_ans)
                 target_q_0  target_q_1  target_q_2  target_q_3  target_q_4
sample_nr event                                                            
1         0        0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
          1        0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
          2        0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
          3        0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
          4        0.086743   -1.085944    1.304110   -0.174707   -0.037001
2         0        0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
          1        0.092376   -1.121655    1.364788   -0.204306   -0.008050
          2        0.092057   -1.119634    1.361355   -0.202632   -0.009688
          3        0.091748   -1.117672    1.358021   -0.201005   -0.011279
          4        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
3         0        0.092704   -1.123734    1.368322   -0.206030   -0.006364
          1        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          2        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          3        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          4        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: It is indeed much faster! About 30x times faster to be exact, which is a massive improvement. The only issue i found is the galloping memory usage. Since the original dataframe has ~6 GB and can potentially grow, preallocating another array of comparable size can be a problem. I'm not sure how Python works with memory allocation in that case.

Comment: You may use [h5py](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) to store the array on disk instead of RAM. Or you may redesign your work into some batch processing logic. This depends heavily on your real use case. You may have it well described in another question.